# Expose some administrative functions on the front-end

Tags: 7, users

I'm developing a web-app for managing non-profit organizations by extending the functionality of the Drupal CMS. What I want is to have only one administrator account (call it super-admin if you prefer), which should be used only by the developer, next there will be a set of roles (coordinator, director, employee).

The idea is that non of those should be able to perform administrative tasks that may broke the site functionality (like managing blocks or menus), but not just that, to provide a cleaner and more compact interface I would like to expose some functions of the admin side to the front-end (accessible only for determined roles), for example, the coordinator should be able to change the role of an employee in order to upgrade him to director.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little broad -- *anything* is possible given time, effort and perseverance!

I find the [Role Delegation](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_delegation) module and similar modules help to give out permissions to trusted users.

I also have been creating an Administrative Panel page using the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module with embedded Views and Blocks for centralized site admin options for users. I usually call this page the `staff dashboard` for my admin-type users.

Without specific problems you're having, these general tips are all I can provide. Happy coding!